# find duplicate records by searching specific column values in a file

Tags: unix

I am new for unix can you please help me to find duplicate record

duplicate based on Name,EmpId and designation

Input File:

```
"Name" ,      "Address",       ËmpId","      designation",        "office location"
"NameValue","AddressValue",ËmpIdValue","designationValue","office locationValue"
"NameValue1","AddressValue1",ËmpIdValue1","designationValue1","office locationValue1"
"NameValue","AddressValue1",ËmpIdValue","designationValue","office locationValue"
"NameValue","AddressValue2",ËmpIdValue","designationValue","office locationValue"
"NameValue","AddressVal4ue",ËmpIdValue1","designationValue","office locationValue"
```

Output file:

```
"NameValue","AddressValue",ËmpIdValue","designationValue","office locationValue"
"NameValue","AddressValue1",ËmpIdValue","designationValue","office locationValue"
"NameValue","AddressValue2",ËmpIdValue","designationValue","office locationValue"
```

Comment: Just to be clear, are you meaning to filter based on duplicate addresses only? In your data you had two AddressValue1, but they had different office locationValues. None of the rows you put in your example are actual duplicates, so you need a little clarification.

Also, you tagged this as unix. Are you expecting only sh/bash-style answers or would perl/python be acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Probably python script will be the best for this:

```
import fileinput

dict = {}

for line in fileinput.input():
    tokens = line.split(",")
    key = tokens[0] + "###" + tokens[2] + "###" + tokens[3]
    if key in dict:
        # print the previous duplicate, if it wasn't printed yet                                                                                                                                                   
        if len(dict[key]):
            print dict[key],
            dict[key] = ""
        print line,
    else:
        dict[key] = line
```

For production use you probably may want to use more sophisticated algorithm to make keys unique, but the general idea is the same.